# Cómo crear varios card de una libreria desde un componente, de acuerdo a número de elementos de contenido

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, dom

*1.- Estoy creando una libreria de npm a través de angular que contiene esto:*

```html
<div class="carrusel">
    <ng-content select="[libContent]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

*2.- Aquí consumo la librería del npm:*

```html
<ngx-lib-carrusel [libHeight]="300">
  <img libContent src="/img.img1.jpg">
  <div libContent>
    <p>prueba 2</p>
    <p>prueba 3</p>
  </div>
  <p libContent>prueba 4</p>
  <p libContent>prueba 5</p>
</ngx-lib-carrusel>
```

*3.-ahora el resultado se ve asi :*

[image: Vista del resultado actual]

*4.- En mi libreria quiero colocar un element `<div class="card">` que se mostraría así:*

```html
<div class="carrusel">
  <div class="card">
    <ng-content select="[libContent]"></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

*5.- por cada `libContent` ingresado desde mi contenido deseo repetir ese `card` para obtener el resultado deseado, que se vería así:*

[image: Vista del resultado deseado]

En pocas palabras el card es muy importante ya que tiene unos estilos que le da vida a la vista y los deseo multiplicar por cada `libContent`, porque ahora sólo está mostrando un `<div class="card">`.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer esto debes usar la directiva ngFor*, con esto podras generar varios componentes dependiendo de los items que tengas en un array por ejemplo.

Docs: https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor

Un pequeño ejemplo con el código que has pasado:

```
<div class="carrusel">
  <div *ngFor="let item of libContent; index as i;" class="card">
    <ng-content select="[item]"></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Podrías añadir un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo. Responder sólo con un enlace se considera de baja calidad. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo que haga falta. Te invito a repasar [answer]. Tienes suficiente reputación en el sitio para saber cómo funciona.

Comment: Pero, si el valor que necesita para la librería es uno de los items de `libContent` ¿no debería pasar `item` a la librería? Es decir: `<ng-content select="[item]">`

Comment: en teoría y yo también pensé que seria un *ngFor pero lastimosamente el libContent alli te traera unefined
apesar que declaras el viewChild , ContendChild o contendChilde  :(

Comment: A tu librería le pasas un array desde donde se esta implementando?

Comment: por eso he creado algo asi @Content('libContend') variable! : any y este tu le das con log y te trae undefined o como tu lo leerias este dato de dato

Answer (score 0):

componente de la libreria card dinamico :

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

componente en donde utilizas la liberia pon un etiqueta en mi caso pongo esto
#libCarruselItem lo malo es que solo funciona con "img" y "div" pero con "p" el contenido lo hace un heigth menor que los otros:

```
<ngx-lib-carrusel [libHeight]="300">
  <img #libCarruselItem src="/img.img1.jpg">
  <div #libCarruselItem>
    <p>prueba 2</p>
    <p>prueba 3</p>
  </div>
  <p #libCarruselItem>prueba 4</p>
  <p #libCarruselItem>prueba 5</p>
</ngx-lib-carrusel>
```

ahora en el ts de la libreria :

```
@ContentChildren('libCarruselItem') libCarruselItems: QueryList<any>;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
     if (this.libCarruselItems) {
       this.libCarruselItems.toArray().forEach((item) => {
         item.nativeElement.classList.add('card');
       })
     }
  }
```